# CodeIgniter frontend do not work

Tags: codeigniter, url

I bought a real estate cms written with CodeIgniter, i uploaded it to my hosting account, but when i try to access my url it doesn't show the frontend part.
I know there is a problem in url rewrite or something like this, if someone can help me, i'll be thankful

By the way the backend work as well (immonador.esy.es/admin/index.php) but the frontend (immonador.esy.es/index.php) dosen't work. This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The community will be unable to help if we cannot see your code and a full description of the issue you are experiencing and explanation of the things you have tried already. For example, what makes you think that there's an issue with the URL rewrite? If you believe this is the true cause of your problem, try sharing the relevant section of your .htaccess file

Comment: ok this is my .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  
    RewriteEngine on 
    Options +FollowSymLinks
  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```